# odataroute same name for post and get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am having one controller Name MailingAddress and in starup.cs i had used  below code to set odataroute .If  i am specifying same odataroute for building 2 entitys i am getting run time error .How can we build two entityes with same odata route so that get and post will be called with same name?

```
builder.EntitySet<BEAccountAddresses>("MailingAddresses");
builder.EntitySet<BEMailingAddressesRequest>("MailingAddresses");

[HttpPost]   
[ODataRoute("MailingAddress")]
public BEMailingAddressConfirmation AddMailingAddresses(BEMailingAddressesRequest beMailingAddressesRequest)

[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("MailingAddresses({key})")]enter `enter code here`code here
public BEAccountAddresses Get([FromODataUri]string key)
```